# How to implement Push Notifications in cordova iOS application

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, apple-push-notifications

I have followed the below steps

My cordova app version is 3.9.2

As per this tutorial
 https://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

I have generated provisionals, certificates and pem file.
After that started on installation of push notification plugin

1. Installing Push notification plugin

   ```
   cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID="JYOSHNASENDER"
   ```

While installing a plugin, shows a warning message.

```
Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-ios version. cordova-ios: 3.9.2, failed version requirement: >=4.0.0 Skipping 'phonegap-plugin-push' for ios
```

So, As per this message i have upgraded my platform through this command

```
cordova platform update ios@ 4.0.1
```

After this, When i'm trying to build the app on device am getting error in `MainViewController.h` file

```
No visible @interface for 'CDVViewController' declares the selector 'webviewdidiFinishLoad:'
```

Note:
Shall i need to add `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method for cordova ios project.

Please let me know how to resolve the issue.

Comment: Could you please share the piece of code where you are getting this error?

Comment: For the same problem i have commented the code.. `WebViewDidFinishLoadMethod` then successfully build the app.
But i got another problem, When server sends a notifications to my app am unable to receive the notification
`server` side does not shows any error. `.pem` file generated successfuly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a known cordova-ios issue where the `cordova platform update` command does not work correctly under the covers and then when you build the updated project you will get the `No visible @interface for 'CDVViewController' declares the selector 'webviewdidiFinishLoad:'` error (see here for details: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9254). The workaround is to remove the ios platform, then add it back, rather than updating it in place. So:

```
cordova platform rm ios
cordova platform add ios@4.0.1
```

and then add the plugin:

```
cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID="JYOSHNASENDER"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I was looking for this solution for 4h :D

Comment: Hi Mike, I have used phonegap-plugin-push for android and its working. Now I want to use same plugin for ios version of the app.. I have created certificates and .pem files. But i dont know where to use that .pem file. Can to pls explain the steps to make it work in ios using GCM.?